# How to pass two parameters to AJAX as data?

Tags: javascript

I tried to do this like:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/add',
            data: { json: JSON.stringify(json), form:  JSON.stringify(formObj)}
```

Where `json` and `formObj` are objects

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The variables `json` and `formObj` are two objects that are referenced in the code, it is unclear to us what those might be with the very limited code you gave us. So is the error with the code that should be referencing it on the server with the post request? Is that end having an issue? What is the error?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just pass a wrapper object containing your both objects?

```
var wrapperObj = {json: json, form:  formObj};
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/add',
            data: wrapperObj
```

Comment: Are you sure about `{ wrapperObj: JSON.stringify(wrapperObj)}`? Maybe just: `data: wrapperObj`

Comment: @Alice Thanks, i changed the answer.